# Cannot write to SD Card

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

Trying to export my application database to the SD Card but it keeps failing.

It seems to be failing at the following line `FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();`

```
public void exportDB() {
        try {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            if (sd.canWrite()) {

                String currentDBPath = "//data//" + "com.rcd.simpleregister"
                        + "//databases//" + "accounts.db";
                String backupDBPath = "/sdcard/";
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Backup Successful!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Backup Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

        }
    }
```

Does anyone know what might cause this?

Comment: Why the 2 '/'? ... I would understand if you had used '\\'..

Comment: Could you post the full exception stack trace, please ?

Comment: you might have forgotten the permission in the manifest

Comment: Actually I just figured it out!  I my database does not have a .db extension, once I removed that (and the extra /) it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the destination file if it doesn't already exist.

```
if (!backupDB.exists())
    backupDB.createNewFile();
```

There is also an issue with your directory path. It may not simply be `/sdcard/`.

Last, if you are working with a Samsung device, you will not be aloud to write to external SD Cards and other external storage mediums with a non-Samsung app without `root` privileges.

Comment: Thank you for this info.  What are my options when working with samsung devices?

Comment: Samsung devices all have a "My Files" app that is aloud to copy data to these external devices. So if you don't want to rely on root privileges, you could make the backup write to an accessible part of the internal storage, which is oddly enough reached by doing `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. Note that while you cannot write to external storage mediums without ROOT, you can in fact read from them in your own app!